# How to add a dynamic number of pictures into a Leaflet popup?

Tags: leaflet, table, dynamic, photos, html-popup

I have a huge dataset of playgrounds I want to represent in a Leaflet map.

Each playground has a different number of photos (between 1 and 13) connected as an attribute value.

The value contains the relative path to each photo, the structure could be changed to e.g. a comma-separated list or anything else that could help. The popup content as an HTML-table should place one photo in each row.

How do I manage to adapt the showing table rows inside the popup dynamically, depending on the number of photos?

Comment: I'd put the pathes into an array and then do a `forEach()` on it to add a row for each path: E.g. `pathes.forEach(path => table = table + '<tr>' + path + '</tr>');`

Comment: @Stefan_Fairphone I think this is worth posting as an answer.

Comment: Okay, thanks. :) I will add some links to the docs, etc.

Comment: @pascatl Well, so much to this. You could have waited until I wrote up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are using a variable called `popupContent` as it is being used in the [Leaflet 1.3.4 documentation for a popup](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#popup). First of all we need to start the table, then add 1-13 rows and then close it again.

```
popupContent = '<table><tbody>'
imgPathes.forEach(path => popupContent += `<tr><td><img src="${path}"/></td></tr>`)
popupContent += '</tbody></table>'
```

This is using ES2015's [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in line 2.

---

I personally would rather use a list as it is more flexible than the rigid `<table>` and style it with CSS ([list-style-type: none](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type)). You could switch between horizontal and vertical display at any time, whereas table rows always (?) are beneath each other.

```
popupContent = '<ul>'
imgPathes.forEach(path => popupContent += `<li><img src="${path}"/></li>`)
popupContent += '</ul>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Stefan_Fairphone I found a temporary way to append the photos as a new table under the popup-table.

```
path_array.forEach(path_array => popupContent = popupContent + '<div class="datagrid"><table><tbody><tr><td><img src="' + path_array + '"height="180px"</td></tr></tbody></table></div>');
```

Comment: This will create `path_array.length` tables in your popup, rather than _one_ table with multiple rows.

Comment: @Stefan_Fairphone In this case you should consider to write another answer!

Comment: @Jochen Schwarze I followed your advice and posted another answer.